# How to call methods depending on instance's state?

Tags: ruby, state, strategy-pattern

I have a class with two states, "state1" and "state2" (there can be only two states, and it never changes since instance's creation) and following code

```
class MyClass

 attr_accessor :myvar1, :myvar2, :state

 include Extension1
 include Extension2

 def func1
  send("#{self.state}_func1")
 end

 def otherfunc
  send("#{self.state}_otherfunc")
 end

 def anotherfunc
  send("#{self.state}_anotherfunc")
 end

end

module Extension1 #handles state1 functions

 def state1_func1
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

 def state1_otherfunc
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

 def state1_anotherfunc
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

end

module Extension2 #handles state2 functions

 def state2_func1
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

 def state2_otherfunc
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

 def state2_anotherfunc
  #do something using MyClass instance vars
 end

end
```

How this code can be improved? (this example is very basic, actual object has two state attributes at once, and i need to override first state's state_machine events based on the second state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to toro2k's comment, I'm taking the freedom of showing how I do things at home in cases like this one:

```
module Ext1
  def f
    puts "state a action"
  end
end

module Ext2
  def f
    puts "state b action"
  end
end

class X
  attr_reader :state

  def initialize( state=:a )
    @state = state
    extend case state
           when :a then Ext1
           when :b then Ext2
           end
  end
end

a, b = [ :a, :b ].map &X.method( :new )

a.f # ...
b.f # ...
```

But this is quite different from the line of thinking that Pavel has asked about in his question.

**Note:** Pavel's instance "state" never changes, so there are no transitions. Should there be multiple states and transitions between them, you would have a place/transition net, aka. Petri net *sensu lato*, embedded in the instance. This would be handled by my `y_petri` gem, in which places and transitions are objects on their own right and belong to a `Net` object, which would be an attribute of the `MyClass` instance, and whose state vector would govern its behavior in the way similar to the one that you or Pavel suggested. Another gem that can be considered is the `state machine` gem.

Comment: unfortunately this solution didn't work in my case. i am using delayed_job to run overriden methods and it caches all classes it processes. so as soon as i initialize first instance, all further instances are executed independently on their state.

Comment: @PavelK., I can smell a design anti-pattern in the `delayed_job`. Parametrized subclassing and monkey patching are elementary Ruby techniques. But I don't want to be too harsh on them; I have written enough Ruby projects to know how difficult it is to make a project work comprehensively with all expected usage patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has many ways to do what one needs to do. Following your chosen path, this is how I'd go about it, Pavle:

```
module Ext1
  def f_state_a
    puts "state a action"
  end
end

module Ext2
  def f_state_b
    puts "state b action"
  end
end

class X
  include Ext1, Ext2

  attr_reader :state

  def initialize( state=:a )
    @state = state
  end

  def f
    case state
    when :a then f_state_a
    when :b then f_state_b
    end
  end
end

a, b = [ :a, :b ].map &X.method( :new )

a.f # ...
b.f # ...
```

Comment: you mean that using case instead of send is better? other than that i don't notice the difference. (true that i skipped the initialization part in MyClass). i'm basically loooking for a way to make above code drier and maybe pollute namespace less

Comment: I think you should make `Ext1` and `Ext2` methods private, otherwise at any time an object of class `X` will resposnd to both `f_state_a` and `f_state_b`.

Comment: @PavelK.: I've done what you asked for: An honest attempt to rewrite  the code while keeping within your line of thinking. Actually your code was not that bad. I'm deleting the last sentence from my answer. There are times when trying to over-optimize the code actually makes the things worse, such as writing `a, b = [ :a, :b ].map &X.method( :new )` instead of `a, b = X.new( :a ), X.new( :b )`. Your code was good enough.

Comment: @toro2k: You're right about that, but in fact, this is not the way I do things at all. I do things in ... lemme make a new answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an implementation of the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), the best way, I think, to implement it in Ruby is by means of the [`Forwardable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module, avoiding explicit metaprogramming. A simple example to give the idea:

```
require 'forwardable'

class MyClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@state, :func1

  def initialize
    @state = InitialState.new
  end
  def do_transition
    @state = FinalState.new
  end
end

class InitialState
  def func1; "InitialState" end
end

class FinalState
  def func1; "FinalState" end
end

obj = MyClass.new
obj.func1
# => "InitialState"
obj.do_transition
obj.func1
# => "FinalState"
```

**Update**: Since `MyClass` objects are initialized with a state and it never changes, probably they are actually [strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), you can modify `MyClass` like this:

```
class MyClass
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@strategy, :func1

  def initialize(strategy)
    @strategy = strategy
  end
end
```

Comment: it was very educative reply and i'd gladly give you another +1 for it if i could. however if i understand correctly, i won't be able to access/change MyClass instance (obj) vars in @strategy instance..

Comment: No, you can't acccess `@strategy`, if you need to, just define accessors using `attr_accessor`. Moreover, if you need to change the state of an object, it is better done by means of methods like the `do_transition` of my example than by accessing directly the `@state` object.